# Thread safe persistent key-value store for python

Tags: sqlite, caching, dictionary

I need to make a big cache of things -- a (key,value) dictionary. I want to be able to save/load this cache to/from disk. The problem is, the dictionary might be too big to fit in memory, so only a part of it can be loaded in RAM at given point in time.

Is there a standard way of dealing with this problem. Am I forced to used a database? I was thinking about sqlite, but it's not thread safe (?).

Comment: see [Serializing Sqlite3 in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296055/serializing-sqlite3-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need a big dictionary you may want to look at using a database that provides a Key-Value store, rather than a relational database like SQLite.

[Popular Key-Value stores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Key-value_store) include:

- [Berkeley DB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB) - persistent storage
- [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) - non persistent (RAM based)
- [MemcacheDB](http://memcachedb.org/) - persistent