# Good example implementation of multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am trying to convert one of my programs to use multiprocessing, preferably the multiprocessing pools since those seem simpler to do. At a high level the process is creating an array of patches from images and then passing them to the GPU for object detection. The CPU and GPU part take about 4s each, however the CPU has 8 cores and it doesn't have to wait for the GPU because no further operations are done to the data after it passes the GPU.

Here is a diagram of how I imagine this should work:
[image: multiprocess diagram]

To help the process along I would like a demonstration with a high level version of my implementation. Say we are looping through a list of images in a folder that has 10 images. We resize images 4 at a time. Then we convert them to black and white two at a time, we can take the conversion as the GPU part of the process here. Here is what the code would look like:

```
def im_resize(im, num1, num2):
    return im.resize((num1, num2), Image.ANTIALIAS)

def convert_bw(im):
    return im.convert('L')

def read_images(path):
    imlist = []
    for pathAndFileName in glob.iglob(os.path.join(path, "*")):
        if pathAndFileName.endswith(tuple([".jpg", ".JPG"])):
            imlist.append(Image.open(pathAndFileName))
    return imlist


img_list = read_images("path/to/images/")
final_img_list = []

for image in img_list:

    # Resize needs to run concurrently on 4 processes so that the next img_tmp is always ready to go for convert
    img_tmp = im_resize(image, 100, 100)

    # Convert is limited, need to run on 2 processes
    img_tmp = convert_bw(img_tmp)
    final_img_list.append(img_tmp)
```

The reason for the specific number of processes and such is due to system performance metrics, this is what will reduce the runtime. I just want to make sure that the GPU doesn't have to be waiting for the CPU to finish processing images, and I want to have a constant queue filled with pre-processed images ready for the GPU to run. I would preferably want to keep a maximum size on the queue of about 4-10 pre-processed images. If you guys can help me illustrate how I would achieve this with this simplified example I'm sure I can figure out how to translate it into what I need for mine.

Thanks!

Comment: There's lots of examples out there. Have you looked at the [doc page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)? It illustrates several scenarios. You basically want a separate pool for each stage where you want to farm work out using a capped number of workers. Think about what functional transform you would apply to an input collection of data to get the output collection, then instead of applying it using `map`, apply it using `Pool.map`. You then use `get` or `join` to marshal data back to the main process as late as possible.

Comment: I have looked at those, but since python is all sequential, I feel like they don't fully illustrate how the processes are working, and how exactly the .join() controls their execution. It seems to me like the .join just completely stops execution. That information is good for a simple process that needs to split up a single function into 4 processes, but my problem would require one pool of processes constantly running in the background while another pool of 2 waits for pre-processed data.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tentative attempt at implementing what you want:

```
...

# Mapping functions can only take one arg, we provide tuple
def img_resize_splat(a):
    img_resize(*a)

if __name__=="__main__":
    # Make a CPU pool and a GPU pool
    cpu = Pool(4)
    gpu = Pool(2)

    # Hopefully this returns an iterable, and not a list with all images read into memory
    img_list = read_images("path/to/images/")

    # I'm assuming you want images to be processed as soon as ready, order doesn't matter
    resized = cpu.imap_unordered(img_resize_splat, ((img, 100, 100) for img in img_list))
    converted = gpu.imap_unordered(convert_bw, resized)

    # This is an iterable with your results, slurp them up one at a time
    for bw_img in converted:
        # do something
```

Comment: I like your example, but I have some questions. The list of images can be as small as 1000 but as big as 100,000, so I would like to limit the size of the queue. I would want 4 concurrent processes running to fill up a queue of max size 10, and keep filling it up as images are getting removed from queue by the GPU 2 at a time. Order doesn't matter, but it doesn't seem like the Queue is being controlled in the cpu..imap_unordered()?